# I18n Localization With Drawer or Bottom tabs navigations in React native app

Tags: react-native, navigation

My App Contain bottom tabs , drawer and stack navigations and I need to support multi-languages for app.
when I changed language from language to other only screens in stack navigation changed but drawer or bottom tabs screens not changed .
I used redux for state management and I18n for Localization.
[reducer of store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J56y.png)
`enter code here`[actions of store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQmEE.png)
[about screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6bLH.png)
`enter code here`[setting screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTPmL.png)

Comment: you need to show some code, no reason why it wont work.

Comment: All things would you need will find here :   https://github.com/Azmaa22/React-Native-Localization

Comment: Did you find answer?, I have same issue